# Cómo dar formato en Angular a un valor con decimales?

Tags: angular, angularjs, pipe, decimal

Tengo la siguiente duda, en un sistema se tiene este formato para mostrar el valor de un campo,

```
{header: ‘Monto Inicial’, with:70, dataIndex: ‘fnMontoIni’, render: Ex.util.Format.numberRendered(‘0.000.0000’)
```

alguien podría explicarme bien a qué se refiere?

Mi pregunta es en Angular como se aplicaría para darle ese mismo  formato a un campo  que se tiene así

```
<td class=“centrado”>{{consultar.montoIni
| number: ‘0.4-4’}}
```

Comment: Angular utiliza el idioma del navegador para expresar el formato de número del usuario. Que formato es numberRenderer? Esa estructura parece ser más bien un string, no número y puede que lo que necesites sea enmascarar el valor, algo como ngx-mask hace.

Comment: Lo que tienes es un diccionario, y lo quieres mostrar es el numberRendered que obtengas de ese diccionario?? No te entiendo tu pregunta honestamente

Comment: @Alfa Rojo, lo que quiero es que mi campo consultar.MontoIni tenga el mismo formato del campo que menciono arriba, mi tipo de Dato es un String

Comment: Y ya lo asignaste a una variable en tu archivo .ts??

Comment: Ya, ya me muestra el valor pero no se cómo ponerlo al formato que viene arriba de 0.000.0000